# jQuery advantages/differences in .trigger() vs .click()

Tags: jquery

In terms of performance, what are the gains (or just differences) between:

```
$('.myEl').click();
```

and

```
$('.myEl').trigger('click');
```

Are there any at all?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

[This is the code for the `click` method](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=$.fn.click):

```
jQuery.fn.click = function (data, fn) {
    if (fn == null) {
        fn = data;
        data = null;
    }

    return arguments.length > 0 ? this.on("click", null, data, fn) : this.trigger("click");
}
```

as you can see; if no arguments are passed to the function it will trigger the click event.

---

Using `.trigger("click")` will call one less function.

And as @Sandeep pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9666547/887539) `.trigger("click")` is faster:

---

[As of 1.9.0 the check for `data` and `fn` has been moved to the `.on` function](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.9.0&fn=$.fn.click):

```
$.fn.click = function (data, fn) {
    return arguments.length > 0 ? this.on("click", null, data, fn) : this.trigger("click");
}
```

Comment: Just to add ... I recently tried using .click() and if failed in Chrome (worked fine in FF and Safari). I switched to using .trigger('click') and it then worked in Chrome as well.

Comment: @Graeck I'm pretty sure you have a mistake in that code.... Cause all logic points at what you are saying is nonsense... Sorry ..

Comment: @Graeck I've had that same thing happen to me too, `.click()` was a shortcut for `.bind()` in older versions of jQuery, that may have been why..

Answer (score 5):

i think that

```
$('.myEl').trigger('click');
```

is better because it saves you a function call as `$('.myEl').click();` just calls that funciton. Look at the code from jQuery source

```
jQuery.each( ("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick " +
    "mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave " +
    "change select submit keydown keypress keyup error contextmenu").split(" "), function( i, name ) {

    // Handle event binding
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( data, fn ) {
        if ( fn == null ) {
            fn = data;
            data = null;
        }

        return arguments.length > 0 ?
            this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
                    //here they call trigger('click'); if you provide no arguments
            this.trigger( name );
    };

    if ( jQuery.attrFn ) {
        jQuery.attrFn[ name ] = true;
    }

    if ( rkeyEvent.test( name ) ) {
        jQuery.event.fixHooks[ name ] = jQuery.event.keyHooks;
    }

    if ( rmouseEvent.test( name ) ) {
        jQuery.event.fixHooks[ name ] = jQuery.event.mouseHooks;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

for performance kind .check here..  http://jsperf.com/trigger-vs-not-trigger
Both are almost same...click() is shorthand of trigger('click').

Comment: This isn't actually true.  Saying that it's shorthand would imply that `click()` were written as `jquery.fn.click = function() { return trigger("click") }`, but it's not (see answer by @andlrc). There is some code run before `click()` potentially calls `trigger("click")`, which is a long enough wait, apparently, for FireFox to determine that the click event is programmatically applied, and won't honor it.  `trigger("click")` is a fraction of a second faster.  I just ran into the same problem mentioned by @Graeck in their comment, and using `trigger("click")` works, where `click()` did not.

Answer (score 2):

Check http://api.jquery.com/click/ :

> In the third variation, when .click() is called without arguments, it
>   is a shortcut for .trigger("click").

It seems they are the same.