# How to click a link with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

If you want to click a link with jQuery, you can use one of the following methods:

```
$('a').click();

$('a').trigger('click');
```

Which is better? (performance, browser support, i.e.)

Comment: you can call with classname like $('.classname').click() or ID like $('#linkid').click()

Comment: I hope the second one is promising as it raises an event `click` to be captured by all the handlers attached to it

Comment: Regarding the performance, here you are: http://jsperf.com/click-vs-trigger-click.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be none, performance wise.

See: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/a-trigger-click-vs-a-click

> This method is a shortcut for .bind('click', handler) in the first
>   variation, and.trigger('click') in the second.

Except you can extend the trigger command.

---

Seems like i was mistaking.

Since click is actually calling trigger, if no function is called.
See: [jQuery advantages/differences in .trigger() vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666471/jquery-advantages-differences-in-trigger-vs-click)

And for performace results, @VisioN linked to this: http://jsperf.com/click-vs-trigger-click

So, basicly using trigger is the fastest way, also i think it actually tells what you are doing, instead of just doing it.

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/a-trigger-click-vs-a-click

> In this form they are the same. As the api reference states:
>
> This method is a shortcut for `.bind('click', handler)` in the first variation,  and `.trigger('click')` in the second.
>
> The second can also be used to attach a function to the event.

Answer (score -2):

Exactly the same. But I prefer $('a').bind('click', function(){});

Comment: I did not downvote, but .bind is deprecated and should not be used, the defacto standard is .on()