# jquery click simulation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

trying to use this code to simulate a click on an object, I am injecting this code in the html..

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
   $(window).load(function() {
      $('#hellothere').click();
   });
</script>
```

Not wroking... at all!

Comment: Why not `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`?

Comment: What type of element is `"#hellothere"` and what did you expect it to do? Run attached handlers? Navigate to the url (if a hyperlink)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rrWhz/ --- it's working... at all!

Comment: no it is a textarea, i want to simulate a click which will trigger other events. but this is not the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `ready()` function to run code when the DOM is ready - http://api.jquery.com/ready/ - the `load()` method is for loading new content - http://api.jquery.com/load/ - and is incorrect for your purposes. You can then use `trigger()` to fire a click event on a DOM object.

```
// run when the DOM is loaded
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hellothere')
         // Set up the click event
         .on('click', function(){ alert('you clicked #hellothere'); })
         // Trigger the click event
         .trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: If you read the `.load()` doco that you linked to you'll see that there is also a [`.load()` event handler](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) - jQuery decides which processing to do based on what arguments are passed.

Comment: i have also tried this before posting the question, nothing seems to work. does it matter that the object i'm trying to simulate the click on is a textarea?

Comment: man if you have define a trigger first you have to define click function on that div. Like This: `$(document).ready( function() { $('#hellothere').click(function() { // some functions here }); // and now if you want to trigger the click $('#hellothere').trigger('click'); });` Now as the DOM is loaded the functions you define in click function will automatically run..

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to simulate a click on object, you should use the trigger method,

```
$(function){
   $('#hellothere').trigger('click');
});
```

Here is the link to docs on trigger: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

This is the code for the click method:

```
jQuery.fn.click = function (data, fn) {
  if (fn == null) {
    fn = data;
    data = null;
}

return arguments.length > 0 ? this.on(name, null, data, fn) : this.trigger(name);
}
```

as you can see; if no arguments is parsed to the function it will trigger the click event.

So use .trigger("click") cause you will call one less function.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9666547/887539

PS:

This is a nice tool to look into jQuery's source code: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/

Comment: But `.click()` with no arguments is just a shortcut to `.trigger('click')`.

Comment: because trigger is faster than click, i have updated my answer

Comment: OK, if performance _really_ matters that much use `.trigger()`, but that doesn't explain why the OP's code doesn't work...

Comment: please post your code as fiddle, normally it works, refer this fiddle,
http://jsfiddle.net/rrWhz/