# Download multiple CSV file attached to <a> using trigger "click" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create and export from my application (**CLIENT SIDE**), a bunch of CSV files. For the export part, this is the path I've followed so far (FYI, I'm also using jquery mobile for the UI part):

1. I create an `<a>` in the HTML with `href='#`
2. I set `download`,`target` and `href` attributes of that `<a>` using jquery, passing respectively the filename, the file content (a string) and the `_blank` value.

This is the code, to make it more clear:

**HTML**

```
 <a href="#" id="btn1" data-role="button">download 1</a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#btn1").attr({
    'download' : 'file1.csv',
    'href' : "file;one",
    'target' : '_blank'
});
```

The resulting button works fine, the file is correctly downloaded as you can see here: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dKwp8/2/) (the downloaded file seems to be broken, but I think is a fiddle thing.. locally, it works great)

Now, as I said before, I need to export more than one CSV file at once. My approach is to create as many `<a>` as I need, set the `download`,`target` and `href` attributes for each `<a>` and then create a `download_all-button` that, sequentially, triggers each button's click. This is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="mypage" data-role="page">
    <a href="#" id="btn1" data-role="button">download 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="btn2" data-role="button">download 2</a>
    <a href="#" id="btn3" data-role="button">download 3</a>
    <a href="#" id="downloadall" data-role="button" >DOWNLOAD ALL</a>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#btn1").attr({
    'download' : 'file1.csv',
    'href' : "file;one",
    'target' : '_blank'
});
$("#btn2").attr({
    'download' : 'file2.csv',
    'href' : "file;two",
    'target' : '_blank'
});
$("#btn3").attr({
    'download' : 'file3.csv',
    'href' : "file;three",
    'target' : '_blank'
});
$("#downloadall").on("click", function(){
   document.getElementById("btn1").click();
   document.getElementById("btn2").click();
   document.getElementById("btn3").click();
});
```

Again, here's the fiddle : [**FIDDLE DOWNLOAD ALL**](http://jsfiddle.net/dKwp8/3/)

This seems to work too, great! **Now the questions**:

1. is the right approach? I didn't find a lot more on the internet about "export a csv using JS client side"..
2. why it does work using the `.click()` and it doesn't work calling jQuery `.trigger("click")`? (see fiddle here: [**TRIGGER CLICK**](http://jsfiddle.net/dKwp8/4/)
3. In firefox, that piece of code seems to open new tabs instead of downloading the file.. is related to the `download` attribute?

Thanks in advance for your help, best regards

Comment: As for firefox in point 3, check out your request headers when sending the csv to explicitly make it download: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloadedcsv.csv"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. is the right approach? I didn't find a lot more on the internet about "export a csv using JS client side"..

   - I'd go with no. Consider downloading a single zip containing all the files in one lump. I'd go out on a limb and say some browsers will not like your approach and anti-spam tools will like it even less.
2. why it does work using the .click() and it doesn't work calling jQuery .trigger("click")?

   - [See here for more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666471/jquery-advantages-differences-in-trigger-vs-click)
3. In firefox, that piece of code seems to open new tabs instead of downloading the file.. is related to the download attribute?

   - `target="_blank"` means "open in new tab". Try `target="_top"` or `target="_self"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#downloadall").on("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("btn1").click()+document.getElementById("btn2").click()+document.getElementById("btn3").click();      
    /*document.getElementById("btn2").click();
      document.getElementById("btn3").click();*/
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dKwp8/6/)

Comment: I don't get the poit of this answer.. you rewrote my working code

Comment: you want click  on downloadall button and download all file that for i am not write new code but some change in your code.

Comment: the download all button was already working.. with the same code

Comment: @IrenPatel You may want to try and explain what you have changed and why. I can see you are using the `+` operator between the calls. What do you suppose this achieves? As far as I understand, you're simply appending the results with no benefit...

Comment: can we download all file in one zip folder?