# When user clicks on one element, trigger a click on another.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some links on my page and I need to programmatically perform a click on an element when the user clicks on another element. For example, when I click on element A, jQuery should perform a click on element A2.

I don't know what this is called, technically, and I'm having trouble finding out how to do this. Is this possible in jQuery?

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Attached an event handler to your first element (#elementA in the example below) and then trigger a click event on the second element (#elementB below)

```
$("#elementA").on("click", function (e) {
     $("#elementB").click();
});
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/Dar8J/

Answer (score 2):

Use following to do trigger event,When div1 is clicked , Trigger click event for div2

```
$("#div1").click(function (){ 
     $("#div2").trigger("click");
});
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/MSSbT/

Comment: +1 `trigger` IS the preferred way of generating an event on an element.http://stackoverflow.com/a/9666577/903324

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a click via click()

http://api.jquery.com/click/#click