# Jquery get data and trigger input file button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $.get('foo.php', function(data){
        $('body').append(data);

        $('.f').trigger('click');
    });
});

//foo.php
<input class="f" type="file" >
```

I have a button, when it clicked, it will get data from another page and append data on body.

after get() append() the data, I want to trigger input file, but its not working

I have try only append without get() and it works.

anyone know why its not working when I use get()?

Comment: `append without get()` didn't get this ?

Comment: append without get() works, but if i use get, its not working

Answer (score 0):

try this it is working

> document.getElementsByClassName('.f')[0].click();

Comment: Should make zero difference.

Comment: safari not supporting trigger but click is supportable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666471/jquery-advantages-differences-in-trigger-vs-click As I said, makes zero difference.

Comment: why don't you try trigger method in safari

Comment: LOOK AT THE CODE!  `$.fn.click = function (data, fn) {
    return arguments.length > 0 ? this.on("click", null, data, fn) : this.trigger("click");
}` It calls trigger!