# Trigger button click for ajax on enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keycode

I need to trigger the ajax call when the `Enter` key is pressed (keycode 13), but this is not triggering the button click correctly:

```
<div class="input-group col-md-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by Asset ID" maxlength="64" class="form-control" id="imageid" name="imageid"> <span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-default image-search" type="button">Search</button>
</span>
</div>

$('#imageid').keyup(function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        alert(keyCode);
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.image-search').click();
    }
});

$('.image-search').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: url
        method: 'GET',
    });
}
```

JSfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4uwaz2yd/)

**UPDATE:**
I added the rest of the functionality, and now the `keyCode` functionality no longer works. I tried creating one `$(function () { //code });`, but this is making no difference. When removing lines 1-173, the functionality works. I think I'm just missing something simple here...

**UPDATED Fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4uwaz2yd/34/)**

Answer (score 3):

While you can call `.click()` directly, you can instead leverage [`.trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/). For some technical insight on the difference between the two methods, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9666577/1464112) will shed some light on the topic. As far as best practice, I'd argue this is more intuitive from a code reading perspective. Also, you had a minor syntax issue in your original fiddle, preventing you from moving forward.

> Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

```
$('.image-search').trigger('click');
```

---

```
$(function() {
    $('#imageid').keyup(function () {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.image-search').trigger('click');
        }
    });

    $('.image-search').on('click', function () {
        alert('triggered!');
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/cuatd172/)

Comment: As it says in that answer, there's no difference between `.trigger("click")` and `.click()` except for a miniscule performance hit because of an extra function call.

Comment: `.click()` is very idiomatic, I don't see any readability issue.

Comment: I also prefer `.click(function...)` rather than `.on("click", function...)`

Comment: I do as well in that sense. To me though, calling `trigger()` in a block of code programmatically seems more verbose than calling `click()`, since we are indeed triggering an event from outside the context of a UI interaction

Comment: To each his own, it's just a style preference. It has nothing to do with the correctness of the code.

Comment: **UPDATE:**
I added the rest of the functionality, and now the `keyCode` functionality no longer works. I tried creating one `$(function () { //code });`, but this is making no difference. When removing lines 1-173, the functionality works. I think I'm just missing something simple here...


**UPDATED** Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4uwaz2yd/34/

Comment: @Matt `Uncaught ReferenceError: ImglyKit is not defined` What is `ImglyKit`? Is this some plugin? Do you need to reference some script library for this?

Comment: @salniro, I don't have that issue, but it's also irrelevant to the issue I'm trying to solve.

Comment: How are you not having that issue? It's thrown right when I fire up that fiddle. Also it's definitely relevant because JS is broken => fiddle broken. Perhaps this could qualify as a new question since this seems to expand the original scope of _this_ question since it was working

Answer (score 0):

You had some errors in your js code:

```
  $('.image-search').on('click', function () {
       $.ajax({
        url: url
        method: 'GET',
       });
   })//you missed this ")"
```

Here is the code that works
http://jsfiddle.net/4uwaz2yd/6/

Comment: @sal niro s answer is much readable and don't forget to pass  "event" parameter to the function in order this to work.                                                                   $('#imageid').keyup(function (event) {..............................});

Comment: @Ravi actually calling `event` in a function block is legal. However, it's common to see shortcut code such as `e.keyCode`. In this case, passing the event parameter explicitly is required such as `function(e) { e.keyCode }`