# Trigger a link_to on right or left key arrow in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

Looking to use my left and right keyboard arrow to trigger a link_to.

My view page has this:

```
#RootDiv
  .nav-arrow
    = link_to lightbox_trip_path(@prev), class: "lbPrev" do
      <
  .nav-arrow
    = link_to lightbox_trip_path(@next), class: "lbNext" do 
      >
```

Here's the coffee script

```
$ ->
  if ($("#RootDiv").is(":visible"))
    $(document).keydown (e) ->
      if e.which == 37
        # left     
        $('a.lbLeft').trigger 'click'
      else if e.which == 39
        # right     
        $('a.lbNext').trigger 'click'
      return
```

I want to be able to only use these left and right arrow key when the `#RootDiv` is visible.

Comment: What is the problem you're facing with the code right now?

Comment: The left and right arrows not working. It doesn't trigger the links.

Comment: @Drenmi I'd want to use left or right arrow and it would be as if you'd click on the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ ->
  if ($("#RootDiv").is(":visible"))
    $(document).keydown (e) ->
      if e.which == 37
        # left     
        $('a.lbLeft')[0].click()
      else if e.which == 39
        # right     
        $('a.lbNext')[0].click()
      return
```

Ref: [Simulate mouse click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3k3vfbk/2/)

Comment: Is there a difference between `.trigger 'click'` and `.click()`? I read somewhere that `.trigger 'click'` might be faster? Also, would it be better to do a `$(document).on, 'keydown' (e) ->` before doing a check if `:visible`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666471/jquery-advantages-differences-in-trigger-vs-click

Comment: I don't seem any benefit of doing check after `$(document).on, 'keydown' (e) ->`