# Jquery click on hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have

```
<table width="60" height="60" cellpadding="0" 
cellspacing="0" border="0" style="float: left; margin: 1px" 
background="images/data/source_red.gif">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td act1="7" act3="8" store="true" art_id="4949" cnt="1" div_id="AA_4949" 
         onmouseover="artifactAlt(this,event,2)" 
         onmouseout="artifactAlt(this,event,0)" 
         valign="bottom" 
         style="background-image: url(&quot;images/d.gif&quot;); cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to make click on the element that rises when `onmouseover="artifactAlt(this,event,2)"`is firing, how to do that?

When I am doing `$('#body').contents().find('td[art_id="4949"]')[0].click();`

i get `undefined` and nothin happens.

Comment: What hidden element? I don't see any hidden elements above (no pun).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `.click()` method.

```
function artifactAlt(obj,event,number){
     $(obj).click();
}
```

```js
function artifactAlt(obj,event,number){
   $(obj).click();
}

$('tr').click(function(){
  alert('tr clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="60" height="60" cellpadding="0" 
cellspacing="0" border="0" style="float: left; margin: 1px" 
background="images/data/source_red.gif">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td act1="7" act3="8" store="true" art_id="4949" cnt="1" div_id="AA_4949" 
         onmouseover="artifactAlt(this,event,2)" 
         onmouseout="artifactAlt(this,event,0)" 
         valign="bottom" 
         style="background-image: url(&quot;images/d.gif&quot;); cursor: pointer;">abcd</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try jquery [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)'s as follows

```js
function artifactAlt(element, event, number) {
  $(element).trigger('click');
}
```

> Usage of trigger('click') will save you one function call as jQuery internally calls trigger for a $().click() function call as pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666471/jquery-advantages-differences-in-trigger-vs-click/9666547#9666547) post.