# Simulate click on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, radio-button

I need to simulate a mouse click on a radio button,but the button is only selected. How do I make functions work for a case?

```js
$("input[value='0']").click();

$('input[name=level]').on('click', function(event) {
  switch ($(this).val()) {
    case '0':
      alert("zero");
      break;
    case '1':
      alert("one");
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
1<input type="radio" class="option-input radio" checked value="1" name="level" />
0<input type="radio" class="option-input radio"  value="0" name="level" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the trigger on the element below your click function. You were trying to trigger a click on a function that has yet to be defined within the DOM.

```js
$('input[name=level]').on('click', function(event) {
  switch ($(this).val()) {
    case '0':
      alert("zero");
      break;
    case '1':
      alert("one");
      break;
  }
});

$("input[value=0]").trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
1<input type="radio" class="option-input radio" checked value="1" name="level" />
0<input type="radio" class="option-input radio"  value="0" name="level" />
</label>
```

Comment: Note that `$(selector).click();` is shorthand for `$(selector).trigger('click');` also

Comment: actually... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666471/jquery-advantages-differences-in-trigger-vs-click

Comment: @charlietfl, you're correct if the `.click()` has no arguments passed to it.